# Why does my recursive function return undefined despite using return?

Tags: javascript

When I try to recursively build an array of each parent index from an element up to body I get undefined returned.

Could someone please tell me why? I can see the expected result just fine but can't seem to return it, even though I meet the stop condition and explicitly use 'return'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div>Div 1</div>
        <div>Div 2</div>
        <div>Div 3</div>
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li id="target">Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <script type="application/javascript">
        const nodeIndex = ($node = undefined) =>
            [...$node.parentNode.children].indexOf($node)

        const nodePositionFromRoot = (
            $node = undefined,
            ancestorIndexes = []

        ) => {
            ancestorIndexes = [...ancestorIndexes, nodeIndex($node)]
    
            if ($node.tagName === 'BODY') {
                console.log('ancestorIndexes', ancestorIndexes)
                return ancestorIndexes
            }
    
            nodePositionFromRoot($node.parentNode, ancestorIndexes)
        }

        const $element = document.getElementById('target')

        const elementsPosition = nodePositionFromRoot($element)

        console.log('Result:', elementsPosition)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just curious though: what do you need this for?

Comment: It's unclear from your description whether you actually want to count text nodes or not.

Comment: Using (ancestor) indices for that sounds like a really bad idea, because as soon as you insert or remove a node somewhere, you will have to re-index the entire tree. That will be much more inefficient than any other traversal.

Comment: "*I however seem to get it almost right*" - what exactly does not work? What is the output?

Comment: I guess I would store references to the DOM nodes in the virtual nodes when they get rendered. Then when you diff the virtual nodes against new ones, you have the DOM node that you might need to remove/reuse readily available. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding your problem? When does your virtual DOM implementation ever need to get from the real node back to the virtual one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to add only a return statement to your recursive calling of the function

```js
const nodeIndex = ($node = undefined) =>
    [...$node.parentNode.children].indexOf($node)

const nodePositionFromRoot = (
    $node = undefined,
    ancestorIndexes = []
) => {
    ancestorIndexes = [...ancestorIndexes, nodeIndex($node)]
    if ($node.tagName === 'BODY') {
        console.log('ancestorIndexes', ancestorIndexes)
        return ancestorIndexes
    }
    // this return statement is required to pass the ancesstorIndexes from the last call to the previous and so on untill the first call ends and returns the result
    return nodePositionFromRoot($node.parentNode, ancestorIndexes)
}

const $element = document.getElementById('target')

const elementsPosition = nodePositionFromRoot($element)

console.log('Result:', elementsPosition)
```

```html
<header>
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
        
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li id="target">Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I just realised this myself but you bet me to it before I could answer my own question! :D Thank you kindly!